# Windows shortcut vs command line behavior

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, command-line, shortcut

I'm encountering a strange problem which could only really be explained by differences in running a program via the command line or by shortcut.

The application in question is a command line C# program which generates barcodes from a QuickBooks company file. I have setup a shortcut which runs the program. If I run this shortcut, I get unreproduceable, strange errors within my program. The errors are not from external libraries. If I run this shortcut via the command line, or the program directly from Program Files with the correct command line parameters, it runs fine.

Any ideas? I can provide more information on the errors, but they have to do with the logic of my program and not any syntax/null pointer/object reference errors.

Comment: We do not have crystal ball. `I get unreproduceable, strange errors within my program` doesn't mean much.

Comment: More information about the errors really is necessary. Offhand, I'd recommend printing out exactly what command is being used to run the program when a shortcut is used in order to verify that it is the same as the command line. The only other potential issue I could guess at would be a permissions error, but, as stated, we really need more information to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

There's one thing that distinguishs starting a process by the command line or explorer from starting it by shortcut: the "working directory". Command line or explorer set it to the directory of the executable. Do the same in your shortcut.

In your program you should not rely on the working directory being the path of the executable (for config file, ressources a.s.o.). Instead determine the correct path at runtime.

Comment: I guess it could be a comment. However, I think it's the answer to his problem and so I chose to not only comment.

Comment: Okay. I'm started actively taking part on SO only recently, so I need to get some more experience.